# Get the Version Number of a Local Docker Image with a Tag 'latest'

Tags: docker

Is there a way of getting the "real" version of a Docker image on my local machine which has a tag `latest` or `stable`?

I had a problem where Rancher server had too old version for rancher-agent which caused the agent to crash on startup. I would like to be able to verify the version of the containerized application reliably. I would at least assume that the `latest` tag points to some other tag with a version number or have I misunderstood the tag system?

Comment: It looks like latest is 1.6.3: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/tree/master/server
mark v1.6.3 as latest:
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/commit/7b06ce359d5d95691abff79d74c096d5160e1ead

Comment: The problem was not about not knowing which version the remote `latest` tag has at the moment but rather which version my local image has which is tagged with `latest`.